# In MATLAB, I want to plot a map with a legend showing different regions.

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I want to plot a map with a legend showing different regions.

For example:

```
my_map = shaperead('my_shape_file.shp');

Equator = [0.1 0.5 0.8];
Tropical = [0.8 0.4 0.6];
Subtropical = [0.7 0.1 0.5];

mapColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon',{'GRID_CODE',1,'Facecolor',Equator},{'GRID_CODE',2,'Facecolor',Tropical},{'GRID_CODE',3,'Facecolor',Subtropical});

h = mapshow(my_map,'SymbolSpec',mapColors);

legend(h,{'Equatorial','Tropical','Subtropical'})

axis off
```

However, this legend doesn't work - it only shows `'Equatorial'` region. Any suggestions?

Additional query: I also want to show city names on the map. How do I (a) find out whether my shapefile contains city names/labels and (b) show these on the map?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any warnings like "ignoring extra legend entries"?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order inside the `makesymbolspec()` to check rather you will see only the first entry there. Also why do you use `{}` inside your legend. Normally its `legend(h, string1, string2, string3)` and last but not least can you upload a picture of your result right now?

Comment: The documentation says *"legend(h,M) associates each row of the matrix or cell array of strings M with the corresponding graphics object (patch or line) in the vector of handles h."* thus my guess would be that `h` is not a vector in your case. Actually the documentation further says that *"`h = mapshow(___)` ... returns the handle to an `hggroup object` with one child per feature."* So you should explore this and probably you will need to do something like `legend([h.ch1,h.ch2,h.ch3],{...})`.

Comment: @patrik yes that's exactly what I get. Thanks all, will explore the child option.